# writing in file in MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

I've written a program in MPI and I want to execute it under 3 or more cores (or computers) and I want to write some thing in file in each processor, for two cores I've created two different files,but I don't know what should I  do for more cores,is it necessary to create separate file for each processor?if yes, so how should I do it based on my code,and is it different for multi computer ?

```
    void main()////it is just for 2 cores,what should I do if I use 
more cores or more computers?
    {
    FILE*fp=fopen("C:\\a.txt","w");
    FILE*fp1=fopen("C:\\b.txt","w");

    if(Id==0)
    {
    here I write in "fp"
    }
    else
    {
    here  I write in "fp1"

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this model, yes, you would need to create a file per process. The reason is that if you have two processes write to the same file, they would most likely end up overwriting each other unless you do something with MPI to ensure that they serialize themselves.

Depending on the data you're trying to write, you could take a look at the I/O section of MPI. There is functionality in there for parallel I/O but it can be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
    int me;
    char filename[1000];

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &me);
    sprintf(filename,"C:\\a%05d.txt",me);
    FILE *fp=fopen(filename,"w");
      here I write in "fp"
}
```

This is probably the hint you required, but usually the correct approach is one of:

- collect data (see MPI_Gather() to start with) an let only the process with rank==0 perform I/O
- if I/O is important or if all the data cannot fit the memory of one node (isn't it the same actually?), use MPI-IO.